# Quick passing of large amount of arguments into a lambdified function

Tags: python, sympy

I have a lambdified function that requires 20 parameters and an array with all the values of needed parameters.

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 19, 20]
func = lambdify(variables_names, function_to_lambdify)
```

Is there a way to quickly pass the values into *func*?

When I try this:

```
func(values)
```

It gives an error as it gets only one argument instead of 20 needed. What I effectivly want is this

```
func(values[0], values[1], ..., values[19])
```

Is there a way to achive this in a nice pythonic way? As *func* is generated function I cannot change the way it takes its arguments.

Comment: `func(*values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the values as such:

```
func(*values)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use star unpacking:

```
In [74]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
      
In [75]: expr = x*y*z

In [76]: f1 = lambdify([x, y, z], expr)

In [77]: f1(1, 2, 3)
Out[77]: 6

In [78]: f1(*[1, 2, 3])
Out[78]: 6
```

The other way is to ask `lambdify` to create a function that will automatically unpack its argument (note the extra brackets):

```
In [79]: f2 = lambdify([[x, y, z]], expr)

In [80]: f2([1, 2, 3])
Out[80]: 6
```